# Moving iOS app from Cloudkit Development to Production

Tags: xcode, ios13, cloudkit

I just updated an iOS app to now use Core Data and Cloudkit. It previously used a Realm database and a framework to sync Realm to Cloudkit.

With Cloudkit Development the app worked perfectly. But now that the app has been released from the App Store and I have deployed the development to production, I get nothing fetched or saved to Cloudkit. A blank screen.

I deleted one Entity with this update and allowed Xcode to create the container in Cloudkit as it does in the Apple Developer video example.

I can't seem to find any good instructions about how to figure out what is going on or if I missed something before I uploaded the project to Apple for review.

Thanks for any help you can send my way.
Blessings,
—Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else is having this problem, I found an answer.

I can't remember where I read it in the Apple documentation, but the solution was simple. I jut needed to create a new container and re-submit the App to the App Store.

Hope that helps someone else.
Blessings,
—Mark